# How can I make all Resources in one place

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I work on C# WPF
I have more than one DataGridView all of them has the same style (Background, row width, column height...etc) but each one has different numbers of columns
***So my question is Can I make one style for these grids and share between them?***

like css in Web

Answer (score 1):

You can create a resource file in wpf where you can store all your style and template. Don't confuse it with the resource file in the Properties directory. You can add a Resource file by right clicking your project in visual studio and adding an existing xaml file or creating a new one.

After that, define all your styles and templates. Then you only need to include it in your available resources

```
<Application 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
x:Class="UsingResourceDictionaries.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="myDirectory/myDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Don't forget to give a key to each one of your style and template, so that you can use them in your User controls